# What does pd.Series.cat.as_ordered() do in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I was looking at some of the source code in the fastai library, and the function `train_cats` reads like this:

```
def train_cats(df):
    """
    Change any columns of strings in a panda's dataframe to a column 
    of catagorical values. This applies the changes inplace.
    """

    for n,c in df.items():
        if is_string_dtype(c): df[n] = c.astype('category').cat.as_ordered()
```

I understand what the function is doing, but I wasn't sure what the `as_ordered` part was supposed to accomplish.

I tried looking through the [documentation on it](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.cat.as_ordered.html), and it was sparse.  To my surprise there's not a lot of information on `as_ordered()` on the internet either.

What's the main benefit of adding this method in this circumstance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at the **Sorting and Order** section in this link: [Pandas Documentation on Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html). It says that:

> If categorical data is ordered (s.cat.ordered ==
>   True), then the order of the categories has a meaning and certain
>   operations are possible. If the categorical is unordered,
>   .min()/.max() will raise a TypeError.

And:

> You can set categorical data to be ordered by using as_ordered() or unordered by using as_unordered(). These will by default return a new object.

Comment: So essentially, this means each columns that gets turned into a category will have an assumed order, and corresponding min(), max(), etc?

Comment: Yes. That is it!

Answer (score 2):

We can get some information from [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html)

```
s=pd.Series(list('zbdce')).astype('category')
s
0    z
1    b
2    d
3    c
4    e
dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [b, c, d, e, z]
s.cat.as_ordered()
0    z
1    b
2    d
3    c
4    e
dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [b < c < d < e < z]
```

---

```
pd.Categorical(list('zbdce'))
[z, b, d, c, e]
Categories (5, object): [b, c, d, e, z]
pd.Categorical(list('zbdce'),ordered=True)
[z, b, d, c, e]
Categories (5, object): [b < c < d < e < z]
```

> ordered : boolean, (default False) Whether or not this categorical is
>   treated as a ordered categorical. If True, the resulting categorical
>   will be ordered. An ordered categorical respects, when sorted, the
>   order of its categories attribute (which in turn is the categories
>   argument, if provided).

Answer (score 1):

This is a helper function that calls `set_ordered` with the first argument set to True.

Here's `set_ordered`:

```
    def set_ordered(self, value, inplace=False):
    """
    Set the ordered attribute to the boolean value.
    Parameters
    ----------
    value : bool
       Set whether this categorical is ordered (True) or not (False).
    inplace : bool, default False
       Whether or not to set the ordered attribute in-place or return
       a copy of this categorical with ordered set to the value.
    """
        inplace = validate_bool_kwarg(inplace, 'inplace')
        new_dtype = CategoricalDtype(self.categories, ordered=value)
        cat = self if inplace else self.copy()
        cat._dtype = new_dtype
        if not inplace:
            return cat
```

So this just sets the fact that you want to treat your Categorical data as having an ordering. This has some more sparse documentation here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.api.types.CategoricalDtype.ordered.html

Some discussion can be found here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14711